# SQL Server In-Memory table use case with huge data

Tags: sql-server, in-memory-tables, table-partitioning

I have SQL Server table with 160+ million records having continuous CRUD operations from UI, batch jobs etc. basically from multiple sources

Currently I have partitioned the table on a column to have better performance on the table.

I came across In-Memory tables which can be used in case of tables with frequent updates and also if updates happening from multiple sources it won't put a lock instead it will maintain row versioning, so concurrent updates is better using this approach.

So what are my options in this case ?

**Partition the table** or **Create In-Memory table**

As I have read SQL server is not supporting In-Memory table when table is partitioned.

What is the better option in this case In-Memory table or partitioned table.

Comment: Which version of MS SQL Server you use?

Comment: You can try using Full-Text Search. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini I am using SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

In-memory tables look great on theory, but you really need to spend time learning the [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/in-memory-oltp-in-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-ver15) in order to make the right implementation. You may find some details disturbing. For example:

- there are no [parallel inserts](http://www.nikoport.com/2018/01/20/parallelism-in-hekaton-in-memory-oltp/comment-page-1/#comment-1403249) in in-memory tables which make creation of rows slower compare to parallel insert in traditional table stored in SSD
- [not all index operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/indexes-for-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15#summary-table-to-compare-index-use-scenarios) supported by dis-based indexes are available in in-memory table indexes
- not all data types are [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/supported-data-types-for-in-memory-oltp?view=sql-server-ver15#unsupported-data-types)
- there are both unsupported [features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/unsupported-sql-server-features-for-in-memory-oltp?view=sql-server-ver15) and [T-SQL constructs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transact-sql-constructs-not-supported-by-in-memory-oltp?view=sql-server-ver15)
- you may need [more RAM](https://thomaslarock.com/2014/06/estimating-memory-requirements-in-sql-server-2014/) then you think

If you are ready to pay the price for using Hekaton, you may start with reading its [white-paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Hekaton-Sigmod2013-final.pdf).

The partitioning itself comes with [benefits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#benefits-of-partitioning) but there is no guarantee it will heal your system. Only particular queries and case-scenarios can benefit from it. For example, if 99% of your workload is touching the data in one partition you may see no optimization at all. On the other hand, if your reports are based on historical data and your inserts/updates/deletes touch another partition it will be better.

Both of the technologies are good, but need to be examine in details and applied carefully. Often, folks believe that using some new tech will solve their problems, when the problems can be solved just applying some basic concepts.

For example, you said that you are performing CRUD over 160+ millions records. Ask yourself:

- is my table normalized - when data is stored in normalized way you gain two things - first, you will perform CRUD only on part of the data, the engine may read only the data that is needed for particular query (without the need to support an index)
- are my T-SQL statements write well - [row by agonizing row](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/), calling stored procedures in loops or not processing the data in batches are common sources of slow queries
- [which are the blocking and deadlocked queries](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/extended-events-doesnt-hard/) - for example, there is a possibility one long running query to block all your inserts - identify these types of issues first and try to resolve them with data pre-calculation ([indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15)) or creating covering indexes (which can be filtered with include columns, too)
- are readers and writers being blocked - you can try different isolation levels to solve this type of issues - [RCSI](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) is the Azure default isolation level. You may need to add more RAM to your RAMDISK used by your TempDB, but since your are looking at Hekaton, this will be easier to test (and rollback) compare to it(or partitioning)